# Did Facebook change where they put the 'via <brand>' when a post is published to the Newsfeed/Timeline via a 3rd party platform?

Tags: facebook

In the past, the logo + via  appeared at the bottom of the post, now the "via" appears at the top beside the brand logo. I tried to search on the blog/support site first, but couldn't find anything. Thanks for your insight! I posted this on the PMD FB page and Jennifer Nieto recommended I post this here.

Answer (score 0):

In newsfeed, the 'via' attribution still appears at the bottom of the post, however if it is an Open Graph action post, then there will be an additional attribution in the first line of the post which can be 'via Sitename', 'on Sitename', 'by Sitename' or a number of other alternatives.

The attributions appear in slightly different places on a users Timeline, in this case I think at the top of the post.